# In Unity, how do I move my character to an object when I click on it?

Tags: unity

Basic question here, and I feel like I'm close but can't quite get it.

I have an object--it's a pot on a stove--that is in my 2D game. There will be multiple pots that appear and disappear in the game, all in predefined places (like on top of the burners of a stovetop). There's also a chef in the game, who goes to each pot and does an action. The user never directly controls the chef's movement--instead, when the user clicks a pot, the chef runs over to the counter in front of that pot, where he can perform an action on the pot.

Can someone tell me how to do this? I'm not only looking for the code but for a "correct" design, in terms of where the various variables and methods should be located. In other words, what goes in the pot's script and what goes in the chef's script? (I'm using C#.)

My thought was that the pot GameObject would have an OnMouseDown() method, to catch the user clicking on it. And in that method, there should be a call to a Move() method that is attached to the chef GameObject.

But what I have is not quite working. The chef moves one small bit toward the pot but then stops. I realize that this is because I'm calling the Move function once and that's it; it seems like the Update method should be involved somehow (the pot's or the chef's?); or maybe I should have an if statement in my Move method that checks to see if the user is at the pot, and if not, runs the move code in a loop. Or maybe the design is just fundamentally wrong and it could be done more easily.

Here is the code I have:

```
public class PotController : MonoBehaviour {

    private GameObject chefObject;

    void Start () {
        chefObject = GameObject.Find ("Chef");
    }

    void OnMouseDown() {
        ChefController chefScript = chefObject.GetComponent<ChefController> ();
        chefScript.Move ();
    }

}

public class ChefController : MonoBehaviour {

    public float moveSpeed;
    private Vector3 moveDirection;

    public void Move () {

        Vector3 currentPosition = transform.position;
        if (Input.GetButton ("Fire1")) {
            Vector3 moveToward = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
            moveDirection = moveToward - currentPosition;
            moveDirection.z = 0; 
            moveDirection.Normalize ();
        }
        Vector3 target = moveDirection * moveSpeed + currentPosition;
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp( currentPosition, target, Time.deltaTime );

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is program the chef to move toward its target destination; every frame in Update() check if the chef is at the target, and if not move a bit toward the target. Then clicking on a pot sets the target position. Something like this pseudo-code:

```
Chef {
  Vector3 target;
  Update() {
    if (chef.position != target) {
      TurnToward(target);
      MoveToward(target);
    }
  }
  SetTarget(Vector3 pos) {
    target = pos;
  }
}

Pot {
  OnMouse() {
    chef.SetTarget(transform.position);
  }
}
```

(this is kind of movement control is also explained in my book; look at my profile)

Comment: Checking if the chef position is the target position can be inaccurate. You should check with `Vector3.Distance` or `Mathf.Approximately`.

Comment: Yeah definitely do that. I didn't mention that detail in order to keep my answer simple. but you should check if distance < threshold

Answer (score 1):

One thing I would be careful about is using the correct input callback. I would suggest one of two things, read the API's on the input methods available, and choose the one appropriate to your desired behavior. Some callbacks only fire if the key is held down, and others fire on a tap.

Secondly, your architecture should change a little bit.
The callback should only set the Target transformation. When you click on a pot, copy the transform from the pot to the target of the move script.
The move script should be changed to automatically strive to achieve it's current target transformation until it reaches it, at which point it will wait until it receives a new target. This is best done by having your movement code in the Update() method within the script. For a small game, this will achieve your goal, and not cause much overhead. (Bigger games with many moving entities need to approach the problem a little differently)

These changes will mean when you click a pot, the target will be set, and on each frame the movement script will adjust the chef's position if it doesn't match the target.

The beauty is that you can reuse the "moveto" script for any other objects, with either a fixed, random, or controlled target transformation to add a little extra to your game. (a rat, or an assistant for instance)

Comment: Thanks; this was helpful. @jhocking's answer was similar and a little more what I was looking for in that it was specific about what goes where--or at least I understood it better. The behavior you describe about being able to reuse the Move script for other objects is exactly what I'm looking for. Unfortunately, when I duplicate my pot and click other instances of it, the chef always moves to the location of the first pot, never to the copies. Any idea why? Do I need to use a prefab or something?

Comment: Glad I could be of some help, @jhocking is describing the same process, but with pseudocode. So long as you understand how to move forward, I'm happy :)
Yes I would prefab the pot. Make sure in your script that you are using the transformation of the object the script is attached to, and not a hard coded transformation. Do a search for "required component" in the unity reference for some reading and examples.